# How do i access JSON data from a variable after its done loading

Tags: arrays, json, object, getjson

var jsonDataNewsFeedGlobal

var jsonDataNewsFeedGlobal = $.getJSON('https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=the-verge&sortBy=top&apiKey=938c99f8bd25454ab488d241db84b493');

jsonDataNewsFeedGlobal.done(function(data) {

```
console.log(data);

console.log(data.source);
```

});

console.log(jsonDataNewsFeedGlobal.data.source);
**My Uncertainty:**

i apologize, i should have been using "data" instead of the "jsonDataNewsFeedGlobal"

this part works now,
my real question is how do i set this data to a global variable and use it where ever i want after its done loading.

Comment: replace "articles" with "status", would you edit your question and add a bit detail about this part?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly here is what you want but please try to give more information in your question.

```
// Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
// and remember the jqxhr object for this request
var jqxhr = $.getJSON( "example.json", function(data) {
    console.log( "success" );

    // Here you can append your data where you want
    $('selector').append(data);
}).done(function() {
    console.log( "second success" );
}).fail(function() {
    console.log( "error" );
}).always(function() {
    console.log( "complete" );
});

// Perform other work here ...

// Set another completion function for the request above
jqxhr.complete(function() {
    console.log( "second complete" );
});
```

Is taken directly from the docs of jquery [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/). Feel free to check it. You can check for [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) and other methods also.